# Who is the guy at the end of the Guardians of the Galaxy 2 credits that says "We Are Groot"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

At the end of the credits for *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2*, there's a guy that says

> "We Are Groot".

**Who is he?** Actor and/or character would be awesome.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### [David Hasselhoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hasselhoff)

#### Character

He is mentioned in the movie as [Peter's idol and fatherly figure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp4yBIW12b4), however he never actually appears as himself. There is a scene though where once Ego gets annoyed at Peter's rejection, he mentions something like:

> I chose the appearance that would be best preferred to you. [transforms into David Hasselhoff] Would you have preferred if I looked like this?

[[or somesuch]](https://moviepilot.com/p/80s-icon-cameo-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-explained/4258023)

Anyway, that's the character part. Now for the sick rap (nah forreals, hang in here I'm dead serious)

#### Music

David Hasselhoff can't be gotten rid of that easily, nope. [He's also in the soundtrack too](https://music.mxdwn.com/2017/04/23/news/david-hasselhoff-declares-we-are-groot-on-guardians-inferno-from-the-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-soundtrack/), in the titular song *Guardians Inferno* ft. David Hasselhoff, where he raps about the Guardians:

#### We are Groot

The significance of that little segment in the credits is related to the lyrics of the actual song; which says something a little bit like this:

> In these times of hardship
>   Just remember
>   We
>   Are
>   Groot

<sup>Ok, it goes *exactly* like that</sup>

This is a callback to the first movie where Groot sacrifices himself to protect the Guardians with a last line of

> We are Groot

Amazing right?

Comment: See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MMMe1drnZY

Comment: Wow, it didn't look like him. I noticed him in the movie, but this didn't look like him much at all. Least, to me. :(

Comment: Hello repcap my old friend...

Comment: Don't Hassle the Hoff!

Answer (score 8):

David Hasselhoff, actor from Night Rider (Peter's idol):

Comment: And Baywatch, dont forget he was in Baywatch, oh and he helped bring down the berlin wall :)

Comment: This is the single most greatest 70's thing I've ever seen.

Comment: also he was in the spongebob movie